# ntile function producing only one group

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing numeric variable with no NAs.

I have previously used ntile to split this variable into 10 groups which using in conjuction with mutate gives me a new variable with observations 1-10 depending upon which group is assigned by ntile.

I have tried using ntile function again for the same process but it only gives me one group in my new variable using the code below.

`test <- percent_phentoypes_broad.class %>% mutate("basal_percent"=ntile(basal_percent, 10))`

I have tried reinstalling dplyr and rstudio but still no luck.

[example of percent and ntile output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcaES.png)

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: @akrun  Not sure how to use dput - here is an example of the input percentage and output decile using ntile - you can see decile 1 is attributed to all observations

Percent           Decile
7.39633919 1
0.33169393 1
0.00000000 1
0.26938043 1
0.10993038 1
0.09727626 1
1.76098478 1
0.00000000 1

Comment: If you can upddate yourr post by `edit`iing it would be great as I ican't see the pattern.  frorm the commentss i.e. `dput(head(percent_phentoypes_broad.class, 20))`

Comment: i couldnt get this to work so have pasted an image of the df in the initial question @akrun

Comment: sorry, I can't copy from image `dput(head(percent_phentoypes_broad.class, 20))` is very simple to do

Comment: percent = c(7.39633918565558, 
0.331693926569827, 0, 0.269380425022448, 0.109930377427629, 0.0972762645914397, 
1.76098478372371, 0, 9.13078797725426, 9.69289827255278, 7.16104392106938, 
31.8293683347006, 20.1874549387167, 0.154612609517265, 2.63157894736842, 
0, 8.81995133819951, 3.71046228710462, 0, 17.7318295739348), 
    decile = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

Comment: I get errorr.  the dput is not complete.

Comment: @akrun 

i changed my code to the following

```test$quintile <- ntile(percent_phentoypes_broad.class$basal_percent, 10)```

and it now works for some reason. Thanks anways

Comment: I was expecting the `dput` to be complete because without the complete structure, I can't copy/paste into console to create the same object that you have

Comment: The issue may be that you have a grouping column you need `test <- percent_phentoypes_broad.class %>% ungroup %>% dplyr::mutate("basal_percent"=ntile(basal_percent, 10))`

Comment: Can you please confirm

Comment: i just tried it with

```test <- percent_phentoypes_broad.class %>%
  mutate(bquintile=ifelse(basal_percent==0, 0, ntile(basal_percent, 9)))```

and get the same issue - i think the issue lies between using mutate and ntile together however this has worked in the past...

Comment: Try with `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: This same problem drove my crazy!!!!!  I finally installed the data.table package, converted my dataframe to a data table, then it worked.  Who knows why........!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To me, using `ungroup()` before mutating the dataframe solved the issue.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
test <- percent_phentoypes_broad.class %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate("basal_percent"=ntile(basal_percent, 10)
```